# Ruby: Get a method's class or module name

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand a mixin precedence situation. If I run `foo.bar` I'm trying to figure out exactly which `bar` will be executed. Here is a snipped irb session where I tried to find out where an array's `assoc` method is defined.

```
2.3.0 :032 > ray = ['cat', nil, 'dog']
 => ["cat", nil, "dog"] 
2.3.0 :033 > ray.methods
 => [:fill, :assoc, :rassoc, :uniq, ... 
2.3.0 :034 > ray.method("assoc").class_or_module_name
NoMethodError: undefined method `class_or_module_name' for #<Method: Array#assoc>
    from (irb):34
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.3.0 :035 > ray.methods("assoc").class_or_module_name
NoMethodError: undefined method `class_or_module_name' for #<Array:0x007ffb8aa286a8>
    from (irb):35
    from /Users/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.3.0 :036 > ray.methods("assoc")
 => [:fill, :assoc, :rassoc, :uniq, :uniq!, :compact, ...
```

If possible I would like to see the methods and their source location that lost precedence.

Comment: @Dom, sorry, I don't understand your comment. I added `last` to Enumerable. It worked in my class but not in an array. I eventually figured out Array has its own `last` that must be running instead of mine. I'm looking for a way Ruby will tell me where `bar` comes from in `foo.bar` to have a faster debugging tool in my toolbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out which class or module defines a method (rather than what file), use [`Method#owner`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-owner).

For example,

```
[].method(:last).owner #=> Array
[].method(:flat_map).owner #=> Enumerable
```

You'll actually find that a lot of the methods that Array *could* get from Enumerable, it actually defines itself (presumably to provide a more efficient implementation):

```
irb(main):018:0> Enumerable.instance_methods.select {|meth_name| [].method(meth_name).owner == Array }
=> [:to_a, :to_h, :sort, :count, :find_index, :select, :reject, :collect, :map, :first, :include?, :reverse_each, :zip, :take, :take_while, :drop, :drop_while, :cycle]
```

Comment: Methods defined in `Enumerable` may be defined in the class that includes `Enumerable` for reasons of efficiency, but not always. In some cases the two methods return different objects. An example of this is [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) and [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) (with blocks). The former returns an array, the latter, a hash.

Comment: If you just want to know the owner (and don't need the result programmatically), you actually don't need `.owner`. For example, `[].method(:flat_map)  #=> #<Method: Array(Enumerable)#flat_map> ` shows that the owner is the `Enumerable` module. `[].method(:last)
 => #<Method: Array#last>` indicates that the owner is `Array`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland True, but in the case of Arrays I don't believe the Array implementation ever returns a different result than the Enumerable implementation would; I'm specifically thinking of cases like `#count` - `Enumerable#count` actually has to iterate over the collection and _literally_ count how many items it finds, an O(n) operation; `Array` already maintains a length record internally, so it can just return that, as an O(1) operation. But yes, `Hash#select` works differently (thankfully; I remember when it did not).

Answer (score 1):

In general, to know where a method is defined you can use `source_location`([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Method.html#method-i-source_location)), e.g.

```
ray.method("assoc").source_location
```

although in this case it will return `nil` since `assoc` is a native method. It will work for other methods, e.g.

```
ray.methods.map{ |m| [m, ray.method(m).source_location] }
```

For native methods you can use [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), e.g.

```
pry(main)> ? ray.assoc

From: array.c (C Method):
Owner: Array
Visibility: public
[...]
```

`?` is a shorthand for `show-doc`.